# How to access an attribute of an object using a variable in django template?

Tags: django, templates

How can I access an attribute of an object using a variable? I have something like this:

```
{% for inscrito in inscritos %}
   {% for field in list_fields_inscrito %}
      {{inscrito.field}} //here is the problem
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For example Inscrito have: inscrito.id, inscrito.Name and inscrito.Adress and I only want to print inscrito.id and inscrito.Name because id and Name are in the list_fields_inscrito.

Does anybody know how do this?

Comment: FYI what you are trying to achieve is not called concatenation

Comment: Thanks. how is called?

Comment: Updated your question and check my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write a template filter for that:

**myapp/templatetags/myapp_tags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_obj_attr(obj, attr):
    return getattr(obj, attr)
```

Then in template you can use it like this:

```
{% load myapp_tags %}

{% for inscrito in inscritos %}
   {% for field in list_fields_inscrito %}
      {{ inscrito|get_obj_attr:field }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more about [writing custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 3):

## Fixed answer for non string attributes

The selected answer don't cover cases where you need to access non string attributes.

If you are trying to access an attribute that isn't a string, then you must use this code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_obj_attr(obj, attr):
    return obj[attr]
```

For this, create a folder named templatetags on your app's folder, then create a python file with whatever name you want and paste the code above 
inside.

Inside your template load your brand new filter using the `{% load YOUR_FILE_NAME %}`, be sure to change YOUR_FILE_NAME to your actual file name.

Now, on your template you can access the object attribute by using the code bellow:

```
{{ PUT_THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_OBJECT_HERE|get_obj_attr:PUT_THE_ATTRIBUTE_YOU_WANT_TO_ACCESS_HERE }}
```