# Using getattr in Jinja2 gives me an error (jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'getattr' is undefined)

Tags: python, attributes, jinja2

With regular python, I could get `getattr(object, att)` but in Jinja2, I get:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'getattr' is undefined
```

How can I use it?

Comment: We are going to need to see more details......

Comment: @gtlambert: this is about the Jinja2 template language, which comes installed by default when you use Flask.

Comment: Try the code in the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157995/how-to-access-an-attribute-of-an-object-using-a-variable-in-django-template/32158083#32158083

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Jinja2 is *not Python*. It uses a Python-like syntax, but does not define the same built-in functions.

Use subscription syntax instead; you can use attribute and subscription access interchangeably in Jinja2:

```
{{ object[att] }}
```

or you can use the [`attr()` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#attr):

```
{{ object|attr(att) }}
```

From the [*Variables* section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#variables) of the template designer documentation:

> You can use a dot (`.`) to access attributes of a variable in addition to the standard Python `__getitem__` “subscript” syntax (`[]`).
>
> The following lines do the same thing:
>
> ```
> {{ foo.bar }}
> {{ foo['bar'] }}
> ```

and further down in the same section, explaining the implementation details:

> `foo['bar']` works mostly the same with a small difference in sequence:
>
> - check for an item `'bar'` in *foo*. (`foo.__getitem__('bar')`)
> - if there is not, check for an attribute called *bar* on *foo*. (`getattr(foo, 'bar')`)
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.

Comment: I found `attr` as [filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#attr): `foo|attr("bar")` is `foo.bar`

Comment: @somenxavier: yes, but that's only needed if there if `foo['bar']` *also* exists (e.g. there is both an attribute and an item by the same name).

Comment: can you clarify it, please. What's the difference?

Comment: @somenxavier: `{{ foo['bar'] }}` will first try `foo.__getitem__('bar')`, and only then `getattr(foo, 'bar')`. The `attr()` filter only tries `getattr(foo, 'bar')`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem here so is to know what's the difference between items and attributes. Is there a basic reference for it?

Comment: Anything that requires `object[..]` subscription syntax in Python code is not an attribute; `item` is not really a standard term here, but that's what I used to refer accessing data using that syntax. You can hook into that syntax by writing an `object.__getitem__()` method for your class. Attributes are anything that is accessed through the `object.attribute` syntax (using the `.`).

Comment: The documentation is the Python language reference: [attribute references](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references) and [subscriptions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), as well as the datamodel on [emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) and [customising attribute access](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).