# If condition doesn't work with object's attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

im trying to write app similiar to Tinder.
I created models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), default='')
    gender = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='liked_by', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User({self.name}, {self.gender}, {self.age}, {self.image})'

class Like(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    like_to = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

I want to current_user wont be able to see user on the home page if he already liked him. And here is my problem to create appropriate if condition. Now it looks like this and doesn't work:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for user in users %}
        {% if current_user.gender != user.gender %}
            {% **if user.id not in current_user.likes** %}
            <form action="{{ url_for('like_profile', user_id=user.id) }}" method="POST">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.gender }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.age }}</p>
                <p>User id: {{ user.id }}</p>
                <p>User likes: {{ user.likes }}</p>
                <p>{{ form.submit }}</p>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This line: if user.id not in current_user.likes - how should i do this?

The function which creates like:

```
@app.route('/profile/<int:user_id>', methods=['POST'])
def like_profile(user_id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    like = Like(like_to=user.id, liked_by=current_user)
    db.session.add(like)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(f'Like has been given to {user} from {current_user}. {type(current_user.likes)}')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: try using getattr(current_user, id), in jinja2 this should  be current_user[id] -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407008/using-getattr-in-jinja2-gives-me-an-error-jinja2-exceptions-undefinederror-ge

Comment: Ok, getattr(user, 'likes') returns the same list but still doesn't work with conditions. In template i tried to use current_user['likes'] and the same situation. So now looks like this:{% if user.id not in current_user['likes']: %}

Comment: what about {% if user['id'] not in current_user['likes']: %} ?

Comment: still nothing...but i hope you understand what im trying to do? maybe problem is somewhere else?

Comment: well, are you passing the variable in the return of the view ? in like_profile, you're redirecting to 'home' view, how does home view looks like ?

Comment: @app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/')
def home():
    users = User.query.all()
    form = LikePerson()
    return render_template('hometest.html', users=users, form=form)

Comment: `current_user.likes` is a collection of `Like` objects, not IDs.

Comment: OK, is it possible to resolve it my way or i should consider something else? Now it looks like this: for example i like user with id=2 and it appears in current_user.likes but Python doesnt "see" this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, maybe someone will be interested. I found some resolution.
First:
current_user.likes was giving Like objects like Ilja said.
I changed from lazy=True to lazy='dynamic' in relationship, now it looks like this:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), default='')
    gender = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='liked_by', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User({self.name}, {self.gender}, {self.age}, {self.image})'

class Like(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    like_to = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Like id: {self.id}, user id: {self.user_id}, like to: {self.like_to}, like from: {self.liked_by}"
```

And it gave me new functionality, i can: `current_user.likes.filter_by(like_to=user.id).first().like_to`
what finnaly returns liked user's ID.
And my home template now looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for user in users %}
        {% if current_user.gender != user.gender %}
            {% if user.id != current_user.likes.filter_by(like_to=user.id).first().like_to %}
            <form action="{{ url_for('like_profile', user_id=user.id) }}" method="POST">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.gender }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.age }}</p>
                <p>User id: {{ user.id }}</p>
                <p>User likes: {{ user.likes }}</p>
                <p>{{ form.submit }}</p>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for trying to help me.