# How to add a Django template variable in another Django template variable?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Model Form in views.py: `a_form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)` and a list: `my_list`.

Both are being sent to the template in views.py: `return render(request, 'index.html', {'a_form':a_form,'my_list':my_list})`.

Every item of `my_list` is a field of the model of `a_form`.

I want to access that item as a field in the template. The only way I could think of doing this was:

```
{% for item in my_list %}
    {{a_form.{{item}}}}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for item in my_list %}
    {{a_form.item}}
{% endfor %}
```

Neither of which worked. How do I accomplish this? Using "with"? A filter?

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157995/how-to-access-an-attribute-of-an-object-using-a-variable-in-django-template

Comment: How do you suppose to access the field of a Class Model? I think it's possible with a model instance. is `MyModel` an instance? if yes you could do it with a template tag

Comment: Sorry @Lemayzeur updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is handling things in python, probably with dictionaries so you can iterate through them in your template as follow:

```
{% for key, value in my_dict %}
    Do stuff with {{key}} and {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you really want to do things your way, the solution is [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).