# How to use variable to get attributes of another another variable in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to populate a CSS grid in a Django template with specified columns and rows. To my best understanding, I need to do something like “nested variables” in the Django template to achieve what I’m looking for. I tried this, but it does not work:

```
   {% for parent_row in parent_rows %}
      {{ parent_row }}
      <div>p1</div>
      <div>p2</div>
      {% for child_row in children_rows %}
         <div> {{ child_row}} </div>
         {% for guy in guys %}
            <input type=”text” value=”{{guy}}.{{child_row}}”></input>
         {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

The {{guy}}.{{child_row}} neither some of the similar variants I tried do not work. I manage to get the result I'm looking for by just writing the whole HTML open, and then by looping through each guy on separate rows, as I can use for example guy.name to get the desired value to each row, but this means lots of repetition.

parent_rows could look something like this for example:

```
“names”, “contact_information”, “hobbies”
```

children_rows could look something like this for example:

```
“forename”, “family_name”, “phone_number”, “mail”, “favourite_hobby”
```

and two records in the guys would be like this (both identical, to ease illustration):

```
“forename”: “Mike”
“family_name”: “McMediocre”
“phone_number”: “123”
“mail”: “mike@mediocre.com”
“favourite_hobby”: “tennis”
```

I am trying to populate the grid to look like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **names** | p1 | p2 |
| forename | Mike | Mike |
| family_name | McMediocre | McMediocre |
| **contact_information** | p1 | p2 |
| phone_number | 123 | 123 |
| mail | mike@mediocre.com | mike@mediocre.com |
| **hobbies** | p1 | p2 |
| favourite_hobby | tennis | tennis |

**EDIT**: Found an answer ot my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157995/how-to-access-an-attribute-of-an-object-using-a-variable-in-django-template). The accepted answer was useful in my situation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157995/how-to-access-an-attribute-of-an-object-using-a-variable-in-django-template).

The accepted answer (custom template filters) was useful in my situation as well. What I did was:

1. Created a directory templatetags under MyApp
2. Created a file named customtemplatetag.py to that directory
3. Copy-pasted the snippet from the linked post:

   from django import template

   register = template.Library()

   @register.filter
   def get_obj_attr(obj, attr):
   return getattr(obj, attr)
4. Added {% load mytemplatetag %} to my template
5. Used {{guy|get_obj_attr:child_row}} in the template